# Query Databricks Model Serving Endpoint with AAD token fails

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-service-principal

I am trying to query databricks model serving endpoint with AAD token.

I first generate the AAD token as follows:

```py
import requests 
import json

url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
payload = {
  "client_id": client_id,
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "scope": "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default",
  "client_secret": client_secret
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
token = json.loads(response.text)["access_token"]
```

For example following command to list endpoints works perfectly fine:

```py
url = "https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/serving-endpoints"
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.request(method='GET', headers=headers, url=url)
```

The problem arises when I try to query the endpoint with some data as follows:

```py
url = "https://<databricks-instance>/serving-endpoints/test-model/invocations"
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


payload = ... # Create model input data
data_json = json.dumps(payload)
response = requests.request(method='POST', headers=headers, url=url, data=data_json)
if response.status_code != 200:
  raise Exception(f'Request failed with status {response.status_code}, {response.text}')
else:
  response.json()
```

This returns an error message:

```
Request failed with status 400

Problem accessing /serving-endpoints/test-model/invocations. Reason:

    io.jsonwebtoken.IncorrectClaimException: Expected aud claim to be: , but was: 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to resolve this problem?

FYI: the same query works with personal access token

Comment: Hi kanimbla, did you manage to fix this error? I'm currently encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model serving doesn't support AAD authentication yet, only personal access tokens (PATs). But it should be supported in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**
You need to exchange your Azure AAD token for a DataBricks token like this:

```
token_response = requests.post(
    f"https://{DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/token/create",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {azure_token['access_token']}"},
    json={"comment": "no comment", "lifetime_seconds": 3600},
)

if token_response.status_code == 200:
    databricks_token = token_response.json().get("token_value")
```

Then you can call the `invocations` endpoint with this token as the `Bearer` token.

I had the same error. After spending a few hours searching the documentation for a solution, I finally found it in this [blog post](https://medium.com/marvelous-mlops/going-serverless-with-databricks-part-2-feccb19162fe) and linked [GitHub example script](https://github.com/marvelousmlops/amazon-reviews-databricks/blob/b68e3f3b7f4acdecb8a815ebebb609f972b308af/amazon_reviews/utils/databricks_token.py#L5).